# Temperature dependence of viscosity in liquids

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, viscosity

I have been going through the literature on viscosity of liquids and their temperature dependence. The most commonly used forms of temperature dependencies are Arrhenius (eq. 1) and Vogel-Fulcher-Tamman law (eq. 2), as shown below

$$
\eta(T) = \eta_0 \exp\bigg[\frac{E_A}{k_B T}\bigg] \tag{1}
$$
$$
\eta(T) = \eta_0 \exp\bigg[\frac{B}{T- T_{VF}}\bigg] \tag{2}
$$

As much as I surveyed, I found that these equations are mostly empirical and there is not fundamental method to arrive at these from statistical mechanics.

Is it possible to obtain a temperature dependent law for viscosity using statistical mechanical models in fluids?

PS: The Arrhenius equation is well established from statistical mechanics for reaction rate constants ($k$) (using transition state theory), but it has not established for diffusive process as such.